# Where can I find a sample PHP MVC application?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I've been attempting to understand how MVC applications are structured and have spent time with frameworks like CodeIgniter and Zend making small test websites to play around with. However I'm still unsure if I completely understand how to separate the logic properly since it still seems like it's taking more time than it's saving.

I learn best from looking at well-written code and I have a feeling there are a few talented programmers on SO.

Are there any good "Real World" examples of a PHP MVC application that I could look over? I've made the mistake of not asking about best practices and instead pick up poor coding practices in the past and I want to avoid making such a mistake moving forward.

Thanks SO!

Comment: There are a number of active projects built on CI and ZF.

Comment: The related links look like they have a lot of people in your situation. Have you clicked through those?

Comment: @melee I looked through a few of the related links that were supplied when I first posted this question but they weren't as helpful as the ones that are provided to the right now. I understand the basics, but I really am looking for solid application examples that I can learn from. Many of the related links are more focused on the concept of how MVC works. Thanks!

Comment: @BoldClock Can you link a couple of some good ones that you've come across? I'm not picky on the framework as much as seeing MVC in action. Thanks!

Comment: @Workman ok - because I was going to suggest Magento (based on ZF), but that could easily be overwhelming depending on your skill level/understanding :P

Comment: @melee I've installed it but the database alone was overwhelming XD

Comment: I hope you can find the best one [click here](http://www.smarty.net/sampleapp1).

Answer (score 4):

I found [this PHP tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html) to be useful when I first wanted to improve my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing an open source bugtracker, you might want to have a look. The code may not be 100% neat and clean, but it's mostly better than worse ;). http://code.google.com/p/bugraid/

Comment: No problem, mate, I hope you can benefit from reading my code ;)

Answer (score 2):

A pretty good basic Zend example is http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/

Or you could just use ZFtool to create a project a very basic program and understand how it is brought together

```
>zf create project <path> from within the bin directory in your zend download
```